# Grouping a Weighted Count in MySQL using CASE

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I am using MySQL Server Management Studio, and am attempting to create a weighted total for the categorization of songs. Here is my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
     TSongs.intSongID
    ,TSongs.strSongName
    ,CASE
        WHEN TUFS.intSortOrder = 1 THEN 5
        WHEN TUFS.intSortOrder = 2 THEN 3
        WHEN TUFS.intSortOrder = 3 THEN 1
        ELSE                            0
     END AS intFavoriteSongCount
FROM
     TSongs
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TUserFavoriteSongs AS TUFS
        ON( TSongs.intSongID = TUFS.intSongID )
GROUP BY
     TSongs.strSong
    ,TSongs.intSongID
    ,TUFS.intSortOrder
ORDER BY
     intFavoriteSongCount
```

The weighting goes as follows: Each "user" in the database has favorite songs, sorted by the intSortOrder. Ideally, the output of this SELECT statement would show each song once, along with a sum of the combined weighted total for the song. As it is now, it shows each song multiple times, once for every single time that it appears on a "user's" favorite list.

Here is an image to explain what the current issue is:

[image: Current, problematic table display.]

How could I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
     TSongs.intSongID
    ,TSongs.strSongName
    ,CASE
        WHEN TUFS.intSortOrder = 1 THEN 5
        WHEN TUFS.intSortOrder = 2 THEN 3
        WHEN TUFS.intSortOrder = 3 THEN 1
        ELSE                            0
     END AS intFavoriteSongCount
FROM
     TSongs
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TUserFavoriteSongs AS TUFS
        ON( TSongs.intSongID = TUFS.intSongID )
GROUP BY
     TSongs.intSongID
ORDER BY
     intFavoriteSongCount

Comment: Unfortunately, this example fails to run because the strSong and intSortOrder must be in the GROUP BY section, or the query will not run. The exact error is literally "Column 'TSongs.strSong' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.". If I add back all the columns to the GROUP BY section, then the query is exactly the same as the one that I am using.